# Improve the performance of a method used to convert an std::string into an std::wstring?

Tags: c++, string, performance, c++17

I have the following method used to convert an `std::string` object into an `std::wstring` one:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

template <class CharT>
inline std::basic_string<CharT> StringConverter( std::string input_str )
 {
  if constexpr( std::is_same_v <CharT, char> ) return input_str;
  else if constexpr( std::is_same_v <CharT, wchar_t> )
   {
    static std::wstring_convert <std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 <wchar_t>> converter;
    return converter.from_bytes( input_str );
   }
  return StringConverter<CharT>( "" );
 }
```

This is used only to convert simple strings like:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

int main()
 {
  std::cout << StringConverter<wchar_t>( "Hello"s ); // returns L"Hello"
  std::cout << StringConverter<char>( "Hello"s ); // returns "Hello"
 }
```

and works well. However it seems a bit too much expensive in terms of performance: in the first case it needs 64 ns to convert the string, while in the second case 11.9. Do you know if there is a better way to write it or if it can be improved in C++17? Thanks.

Comment: If you run the first case a second time, I bet it will be better. At first execution with a `wchar_t`, you create the converter which should take some time.

Comment: @Fareanor yes you are right since the converter is `static`. The problem is that even if i pass it a `char` (like the second case) it needs however 11.9 ns. It seems a bit too much for me.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to be faster than a single return statement ? If it's too long for you, maybe upgrade to a better machine XD Joking aside, did you enable compiler optimization ? If not, it's quite pointless to profile execution time (to be strict you also need to have a fixed CPU rate, etc... to have more useful results).

Comment: @Fareanor yes they are all enabled. The fact is that maybe there is a different and better way to write the function in general to match its purposes? That was the initial question.

Comment: Why would you use a runtime conversion to convert string literals, instead of just declaring them with the correct type at compile-time to begin with?

Comment: @RemyLebeau what do you mean exactly? Can you provide me a working example?

Comment: The `if constexpr` are resolved at compilation time. So, in the case you use a `char`, your function is equivalent to: `std::string StringConverter(std::string input_str) {return input_str;}` You may want to get your string by const reference instead than by copy but I'm afraid you can't do much more than that.

Comment: @Fareanor yeah but the problem is that cppcheck gives me an error:../include/ptc/print.hpp:88:6: error: `Found a exit path from function with non-void return type that has missing return statement [missingReturn]
     }
     ^`

Comment: @GianlucaBianco `"Hello"` is `const char[6]` and `"Hello"s` is `std::string`, whereas `L"Hello"` is `const wchar_t[6]` and `L"Hello"s` is `std::wstring`. There is no good reason to convert a `char`-based string literal to `std::wstring` at runtime if you can just start with a `wchar_t-based string literal to begin with.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco On a side note, you should have an `else` on `return StringConverter<CharT>( "" );` so the `if constexpr`s can eliminate it properly. Otherwise, you will end up with an unreachable `return` for `char` and `wchar_t` types that may or may not be optimized out, and will likely issue a warning.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I feel stupid but don't understand the point. If I don't use `if constexpr` I cannot have a working working function which check for types. This is the only working implementation I found so far, maybe you can show me your with a full answer if possibile.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco my point is, `StringConverter<wchar_t>( "Hello"s )` is a waste when you can just use `L"Hello"s` instead. And `StringConverter<char>( "Hello"s );` is a waste when you can just use `"Hello"s` instead. The results are exactly the same, but completely evaluated at compile-time, not runtime.

Comment: @RemyLebeau well that's obvious ahah but I need of course that specific function for other purposes, that was only an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clearly avoid copy/move in case you don't do any conversion (`std::string` -> `std::string`) and just pass and return by reference:

```
template <class CharT>
std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<CharT, char>,
                   const std::basic_string<CharT>&,
                   std::basic_string<CharT>>
StringConverter(const std::string& input_str)
{
  if constexpr( std::is_same_v <CharT, char> ) {
    return input_str;
  } else if constexpr( std::is_same_v <CharT, wchar_t> ) {
    static std::wstring_convert <std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 <wchar_t>> converter;
    return converter.from_bytes( input_str );
  } else {
    return StringConverter<CharT>( "" );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! With this implementation the time of the first if/else condition is halved! Thanks.

Comment: You may have a look also at this one, nobody already answered correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73632337/performance-improvements-of-a-method-which-check-if-a-string-is-an-ansi-escape-s?noredirect=1#comment130027474_73632337

Comment: @GianlucaBianco please be very careful with this solution. https://godbolt.org/z/nKzdhzoch

Comment: @Alexander not a problem, I have to deal with very small strings

Comment: @GianlucaBianco: it is not an issue of length of string, but temporary lifetime. Adding a `template <typename>void StringConverter(std::string&&) = delete;` should avoid the issue.

Comment: @Jarod42 it gives me error if trying to add it

Comment: @GianlucaBianco: Alexander's example produces dangling pointer, such as `char& c = MakeString()[0];`. Above suggested (deleted) overload forbids such wrong usage (but forbid also some regular usage).

Comment: @Jarod42 so basically I cannot use this overload since it forbids regular usage

Comment: `const auto& dangling = StringConverter("dangling");` but `const auto ok = StringConverter("ok");`. The extra deleted overload block both. And you need `const std::string s = /*...*/; const auto& ok2 = StringConverter(s);`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is possible to improve performances of it but you sure can improve a bit on other grounds.

If you rely on template specialization, you can make the code a bit simpler (readable).

```
template <typename CharT>
std::basic_string<CharT> StringConverter(const std::string & input_str);

template <>
std::string StringConverter(const std::string & input_str)
{
    return input_str;
}

template <>
std::wstring StringConverter(const std::string & input_str)
{
    static std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    return converter.from_bytes(input_str);
}
```

Your function now works only for the two given specializations and consequently you don't need that ugly `return` statement to handle the case it is called with something else than `char` or `wchar_t`.

Moreover, taking the argument through a `const` reference instead of a plain copy may improve performances a bit.

**Note:** Since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16` seems to be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, this implementation seems to improve the performance a bit (a few ns). I see no big differences in passing the string by copy or by reference however.

Comment: If you were to copy bigger strings, you'll see the difference for sure :)

Comment: Moreover, since your example uses temporary string literals, the compiler may elide the unnecessary copies anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a replacement for `std::codecvt_utf8_tf16`? Since it will be deprecated.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco I did look for it but could not find one. It seems the standard did not provide it yet. But I may have missed it (I admit I didn't take that much time to find it)

Comment: @GianlucaBianco `wstring_convert` is also deprecated, with no replacement in sight. So, eventually, you will need to rewrite the entire code for the `wchar_t` case. Use a 3rd party Unicode library, like libiconv, icu, etc or equivalent platform API