# Performance improvements of a method which check if a string is an ANSI escape sequence?

Tags: c++, performance, c++17, ansi-escape

Let's suppose I have a class with a private method `is_escape` which check if an input string is and ANSI escape sequence. This method is then used in another public method, into an if/else condition:

```
#include <string>

enum class ANSI { first, generic };

template <class T_str>
class foo
 {
  private:
   template <typename T>
   static constexpr bool is_escape( const T& str, ANSI&& flag ) { /* implementation */ }

  public:
   template <class T>
   void public_method( T str ) // T can be also an int, double etc...
    {
     if ( is_escape( str ) ) { /* do something */ }
    }
 };
```

The implementation of the `is_escape` method is the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
static constexpr bool is_escape( const T& str, ANSI&& flag )
 {
  if constexpr( std::is_convertible_v <T, std::basic_string_view<T_str>> && ! std::is_same_v<T, std::nullptr_t> )
   {
    switch( flag )
     {
      case( ANSI::first ): 
       {
        return ( ! std::basic_string_view<T_str>( str ).rfind( "\033"s, 0 ) ) && 
               ( std::basic_string_view<T_str>( str ).length() < 7 );
       }
      case( ANSI::generic ):
       {
        return ( std::basic_string_view<T_str>( str ).find( "\033"s ) != std::basic_string_view<T_str>::npos );
       }
     }
   }
  return false;
 }
```

Is there a better way to write the method in order to improve its performances (in C++17)? Thanks.

Comment: You can check if the length is less than 7 first. It avoid reading more than 7 characters. For the second case, if the string is big, then you can check the compiler generate SIMD instruction. otherwise there is not much to do apart from reordering the conditions based on their probability (profile guided optimization should do that and the processor is able to do prediction too if this code is done in a loop and can be actually predicted). Misprediction is generally a bit expensive. A find of `'\033'` should also be faster than `"\033"`, especially for short strings.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks a lot. If you provide me a full answer with the new function I can vote it as the best one.

Comment: `"\033"sv` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Jarod42 what is that v?

Comment: [`operator ""sv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv) to create `std::stringview`.

Comment: @Jarod42 In which namespace is it contained? Is it C++17 or 20?

Comment: Have you followed the link? *"`std::literals::string_view_literals::operator""sv` (since C++17)"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I improved the performances of the function with this signature:

```
template <typename T>
static constexpr bool is_escape( const T& str, const ANSI& flag )
 {
  if constexpr( std::is_convertible_v <T, std::basic_string_view<T_str>> && ! std::is_same_v<T, std::nullptr_t> )
   {
    switch( flag )
     {
      case( ANSI::first ): 
       {
        return ( std::basic_string_view<T_str>( str ).length() < 7 ) && ( str[0] == '\033' );
       }
      case( ANSI::generic ):
       {
        return ( std::basic_string_view<T_str>( str ).find( '\033' ) != std::basic_string_view<T_str>::npos );
       }
     }
   }
  return false;
 }
```